# Question on jvm-wide properties and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, security, concurrency, jakarta-ee

I need to use (at the moment) some java apis that -unfortunatelly- can be "configured" only via jvm properties.
I understand that this can affect multithreading, since it can be the case that one thread modifying the properties can affect the others running.
So I thought to do this inside a synchronized method e.g.

```
public static sychronized void someMethod(){
   Security.setProperty("responderURL",IP);
   //do code here
}
```

It seems it is ok, but I was wondering if there any pitfalls on this and whether there is any kind of design pattern for cases like these?

Thanks

Comment: there are pitfalls as usual: stale reads. There is no difference between System properties and any shared variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a synchronized static method, it synchronizes on the class that the method is in. This means that only one method in that class will be able to run at a time. If that solves your problem, then perfect.

However, if any other method in the JVM modifies those properties outside of that class or outside of a method that's synchronized on the class, then your efforts won't have any effect.

Comment: Note also that as the properties are static, they might be read somewhere random (class initialisation probably) and stashed in, say, another static field. It's not just actually mutable statics that are evil, but any static that can change from run to run.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to synchronize , `System.setProperty` is already synchronized method, and although `System.getProperty` is not synchronized, Properties class extends HashTable which has syncronized method to access its key-value pairs.As a result, you dont need to do worry about synchronizing issues..

EDIT :

Some clarifications about my answer ;

1.If your method should work as an atomic unit, it should  be synchronized , such as ;

```
    public static sychronized void someMethod(){
       if (System.getProperty("responderURL")==null)
           System.setProperty("responderURL",IP);
       //do code here
       //some code
       URL url  = new URL(System.getProperty("responderURL"),8080,"test.txt");
    }
```

You should synchronized your method, because while Thread 1 is checking responderURL property , Thread 2 could set this property.

2.But if your method  sets only responderURL property, and its functionality does not depend respondrURL property current value, you dont need to synchronize your method..

```
  public static  void someMethod(){
            System.setProperty("responderURL",IP);
           //do code here
           //some code
           URL url  = new URL(IP,8080,"test.txt");
      }
```

Comment: @Gursel:So if thread A sets the Security.property to IP1, and thread B tries to set Security.property to IP2 what will happen?Will it not IP2 override IP1?

Comment: It will overwrite, but synchronization won't protect you from that.

Comment: @Kaj:Why not?If it is synchronized the threadB will override the IP after threadA has exited synchronized method.Right?

Comment: Thread B, will wait until Thread A finishes setting property.. But if you want to solve lost update issues, you should write your own synchronized method..

Comment: @Gursel:Not sure If I get your point.My intent is that threadA sets IP1 to JVM and IP1 is used and threadB sets IP2 in JVM and IP2 is used

Comment: If they are different properties, then it would not be a problem. If both threads try to set same property IP1, then there would be a lost update problem.  But your case looks like the second case, because you set responderURL property.

Comment: could the downvoter explain his reasoning?. I could correct my answer by this way.

Comment: I would downvote as well: the point of the synchronized block seems to be to ensure that both the setProperty *and* the call to the external code relying on the property happen atomically.  In other words, if you removed the synchronization, two threads both executing that method would have a problem.  You could get T1: setProperty A=1, T2: setProperty A=2, T1: "do code here" (expecting A=1).

Comment: @bkail, well I do understand your concern, I did also express same concerns.. System.setProperty is synchronized and therefore it is an atomic operation, well if there is requirement as you have expressed,  that method should be synchronized also..

Comment: @user384706. Ah, so your "do code here" is the only place where you and the rest of the VM reads that parameter? It will work in that case, but only in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using synchronized won't help you here. The only thing `synchronized` does in your example is ensure that two threads cannot call *your synchronized method* simultaneously.

```
public class Foo {
  public static synchronized void bar() {
       //...    
  }
}
```

is exactly the same as

```
public class Foo {
  public static void bar() {
      synchronized (Foo.class) {
       //...    
      }
  }
}
```

i.e. only code that can see `Foo.class` and synchronizes on it will be affected by your synchronization.  Since code in whatever libraries you are calling obviously does not know about Foo.class, synchronizing on it will not have any effect.

If you want to *guarantee* that these system properties are set before any code runs which might read the values can possibly run, the most bulletproof way is to pass them as -D arguments to the java command which starts the JVM, e.g.
`java -DresponderURL=http://foo.bar`.

The next best approach is, as you are doing, set the properties in some method called *early in VM startup*.  It is always preferable to do it with command-line arguments if possible, though, for this reason:  If any such properties are read in static{} blocks in the libraries you're using, those blocks *may* run before your code does, because Java's bytecode verifier may cause those classes to be initialized before your code does anything that calls them (you can avoid this by passing `-Xverify:none` to the Java command, but if you can do that, you might as well just set the system properties there anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If this is one time configuration, you do this inside a static initialization block. If not, what you have is the classic reader-writer problem.  The `java.util.concurrent` javadocs have some good sample solutions.